# How to wait function to finish before asking new question with inquirer

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I'm looping inquirer like:

```
function start() {
  let stop = 0; 
  const askQuestion = () => {
    inquirer
      .prompt([
        {
          type: "list",
          name: "action",
          message: "WHAT TO DO?",
          choices: ["books", "other", "exit"],
          loop: true,
        },
      ])
      .then((answers) => {
        if (stop == 0) {
          if (answers.action == "books") {
            fetchBooks();
          } else if (answers.action == "exit") {
            stop = 1;
            return;
          }
          askQuestion();
        }
      });
  };
  askQuestion();
}

start();
```

This works, but my fetchBooks function makes an api call:
(books array that I used in foreach is a separate json file)

```
function fetchBooks() {
  var len = 0;
  var booksAll = [];
  books.forEach((book) => {
    var bookname = APICALL(book.id).then((bxk) => {
      var b = { name: book.name, short: bxk.text };
      booksAll.push(b);
      len++;
      if (len === books.length) {
        console.log(booksAll);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

(Please don't mind the correctness of the fetchbooks function, I've polished it to share here, normally it works pretty fine, my problem is not with that)

The thing is, right now this code works.

But when I pick "books" from inquirer, inquirer doesn't wait for asking the question again before I do something with the results from my first answer, fetchBooks execute with the same time of new question from inquirer. So they overlap.

How can I make inquirer to wait before fetchBooks() returns something to screen and then it asks in the new line?

Comment: Why did you tag this question with `async`-`await` when you're not using that?

Comment: You'd need to make fetchBooks return a promise, which you could await.  I noticed you put "async-await" keyword on the post.  It would be my recommendation to use that technology.

Comment: @Bergi, I've added that tag because I need it but I don't know how to implement that to my code, I've tried putting those everywhere but I just make it worse. :/ Thats why asked here to be honest

Comment: @James I've added that tag because I need it but I don't know how to implement that to my code, I've tried putting those everywhere but I just make it worse. :/ Thats why asked here to be honest

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this

```
function start() {
  let stop = 0; 
  const askQuestion = () => {
    inquirer
      .prompt([
        {
          type: "list",
          name: "action",
          message: "WHAT TO DO?",
          choices: ["books", "other", "exit"],
          loop: true,
        },
      ])
      .then((answers) => {
        if (stop == 0) {
          if (answers.action == "books") {
            fetchBooks().then(() => askQuestion());
          } else if (answers.action == "exit") {
            stop = 1;
            return;
          }
          
        }
      });
  };
  askQuestion();
}

start();
```

```
function fetchBooks() {
    var len = 0;
    var booksAll = [];
    return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        books.forEach((book) => {
            var bookname = APICALL(book.id).then((bxk) => {
                var b = { name: book.name, short: bxk.text };
                booksAll.push(b);
                len++;
                if (len === books.length) {
                    console.log(booksAll);
                    resolve()
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters have said, `async-await` is your friend here. If you rewrite your function to use `async` and `await`, all the logic becomes simpler:

```js
async function askQuestion() {
  const answers = await inquirer
    .prompt([
      {
        type: "list",
        name: "action",
        message: "WHAT TO DO?",
        choices: ["books", "other", "exit"],
        loop: true,
      }
    ]);

  if (answerrs.action === "books") {
    await fetchBooks();
    askQuestion();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've tested the answer below because it was earlier and it worked, yours look more clean but I'm a bit scared to break it when its working :) But I will try it in the next move for sure, now I need to figure out what I must have do if I want to give more options to user inside a question like question->answer->another question depending on the answer->other answers ...